# Create SSB (Site Specific Browser) EMR Applications

Tags: web-applications, air, cross-browser, medical, devforce

I am planning to create a Web Application (EMR) for Physicians/Nurses and other Medical folks.
Since these folks are not technical, they frequently tend to stumble with basic operations of the browser and that becomes a hurdle in their patient management. 
I have noted that most hospitals use a Custom EMR Applications in their intranet. Not sure if the application can be accessed from out side the hospitals also? In my case I plan to make it accessible from anywhere.

I was planning to create Web Application with Site Specific Browser (SSB) in order to have a complete control over the the browser buttons.
 Thus providing only those controls that the doctors can EASILY understand.

I have looked at MailPlane(for Gmail) and some sites which conduct Online exams.
 I think those folks are using SSB.

So my question is, 
1) What are the best tools available to create SSB (Site Specific Browser) Applications that will work on Win/Mac (Linux would be good too)?

2) Are SSB's a common UI Paradigm or is there something better than that? Or should SSB UI model be dumped in favor of a regular Web Application(with more training given to the doctors :))?

3) Would SSB UI paradigm be more easier to adopt to mobile devices (Ipad, android..etc) - if needed down the line.

One of the drawbacks of SSB as compared to Web Applications is that, whenever we add new features we will have to update the application on each client computer.
Unlike regular web applications, where we just cut the new release and restart the tomcat.
So there is some remote desktop management of the application needed in case of SSB (Correct me if I am wrong).

As of now, I just know Adobe AIR has got very good development support for SSB.
Not sure if there are others which are better?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're talking about a "locked-down" browser instance with no back/forward buttons that can only go to a single site.  You also tagged the question with "adobe-air", so I think you're looking at desktop-based RIA options.

Both AIR and Silverlight's Out-Of-Browser mode offer options for web-delivered applications that run on the client side.  Both run completely outside of the browser and can self-update when new versions are released.  Depending on the requirements for your application, either may be a good option for you.

I don't know much about AIR, but I have worked with Sliverlight.  The OOB mode works much like any other application, and the self-update works well.  You can't do much of use without a package of controls, and I would recommend a more robust services layer than WCF RIA Services. (e.g. IdeaBlade's DevForce product.)  If you go with Silverlight you'll also want to learn about MEF and/or PRISM to understand modular application development.

Comment: I am looking at a RIA with custom browser controls. Since the backend will be in Java, I was thinking about AIR and not Silverlight. I was inclining more towards AIR after reading this http://www.sdtimes.com/content/article.aspx?ArticleID=34162&page=5